# Saving custom fields of user with Ajax request

Tags: users, ajax, jquery

I am using an Ajax (POST) request to update the current user profile.
So far I can successfully update the user fields (like `fullName`) but I cannot seem to update custom fields.

I have tried adding the custom fields within the `fields` array (just like when using an HTML form), but this doesn't seem to work.

Below my code:

```
$('.js-update-profile').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    var fields = [];
    fields['nickname'] = 'Nickname';
    const params = {
        CRAFT_CSRF_TOKEN: csrfTokenValue,
        userId: player.id,
        fields: fields,
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: '/actions/users/save-user',
        type: 'POST',
        data: params,
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (params) {
            console.log(params);
        }
    });
});
```

When I excute this code I'm getting a successfull message `User saved`, but the custom fields are not updated.

Am I doing something wrong with setting up the params?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wager this is the problem:

```javascript
var fields = [];
fields['nickname'] = 'Nickname';
```

JavaScript doesn't have associative arrays like PHP. The fact that this works at all is only a quirk in JavaScript – Arrays are objects, so you can assign properties to them. So you're adding a `fields.nickname` property, but that's not part of the array. So jQuery can't really pick up the property, as the array itself is still empty.

Use an object instead, then it should work:

```javascript
const fields = {
    nickname: 'Nickname',
};
```

If you need to add properties dynamically:

```javascript
const fields = {};
fields.nickname = 'Nickname';

// for element fields, use an array of IDs
fields.category = [42, 50]
```

To debug a problem like this, open up the [Network tab](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/network_monitor/index.html) in your browser's devtools. There you can see and inspect the payload for the AJAX request. Check the request payload to see if you data is actually getting transmitted.

Comment: This worked! But now I need to add something to the object (example of HTML `field[category][]`), how would I do that?

Comment: @J1989 I've added an example snippet to the answer. Also check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_objects